# Is the cup in Luke 22:42 God's wrath we see in other Scriptures or the cup of Redemption we see in Exodus?

Tags: matthew, luke, exodus, isaiah, jeremiah

> **Matthew 26:27-29**
> Then he took the cup, gave thanks and offered it to them, saying, Drink from it, all of you.  This is my blood of the covenant which is poured out for many for the forgiveness of sins.

> **Luke 22:42**
> Father, if you are willing, take this cup from me...

We see in Isaiah 51:17,22, Jeremiah 25:15, Revelation 14:10 and 16:19, Habakkuk 2:16 a cup of God's wrath.

We see in Isaiah 53:4,5 where Jesus took away our transgressions and gave us peace.

Exodus 6 are the four "I wills" of God and the third one is that God will redeem us with an outstretched arm and with mighty acts of judgment.

I believe this third cup is the cup of redemption that Jesus spoke of at the Passover Meal.  IS IT ALSO THE CUP OF WRATH WE SEE IN THE OTHER SCRIPTURES ABOVE?

Comment: Ex 6 contains about seven "I will"s.

Comment: **Topical Bible Study** A topical study can be misleading because it takes words out of context, and lumps them together illegitimately,  Each must be considered in "Context." When this word, "cup" is studied expository, they are seen to be different subjects.

Comment: A cup is sometimes just a cup.

Comment: God's wrath and his redemption are the same thing, or at least two sides of the same coin. God redeems his people through his wrath on their enemies (sin-and-death being the ultimate enemy).

Answer (score 1):

The cup mentioned in Luke 22:42 is neither the cup of God's wrath nor the cup of redemption. It is the cup of suffering and death. This view is shared by many, probably most, commentaries. Typical of them is [Gill](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/luke/22-42.htm) who says:

> *remove this cup from me*; meaning, either his present sorrows and distress, or his approaching sufferings and death, which he had in
> view.

As a fully human being (as well as a fully divine one) Jesus naturally wanted to avoid death. In Luke's version of this episode, portrayed earlier in the chapter, Jesus even commissions his disciples to obtain swords, knowing that the Temple authorities sought to arrest him and put an end to his life:

> Whoever has no sword is to sell his coat and buy one... 38 They said,
> “Lord, look, here are two swords.” And He said to them, “It is
> enough.”

When he entered Gethsemane, Jesus strictly warned his now-armed disciples to stay awake and keep watch. He then went further into the garden and desperately prayed to avoid death, submitting himself to the Father's will but also apparently hoping that his disciples would warn him of danger and even fight for him, so he could escape death for the time being and bring the Good News to as many people as possible. When they were found sleeping (three times according to other accounts) they failed their assigned mission at a critical time. As a result, Jesus was arrested and soon put to death.

> He was praying very fervently; and His sweat became like drops of
> blood, falling down upon the ground. 45 When He rose from prayer, He
> came to the disciples and found them sleeping from sorrow, 46 and said
> to them, “Why are you sleeping? Get up and pray that you may not enter
> into temptation.” 47 While He was still speaking, behold, a crowd
> came, and the one called Judas, one of the twelve, was preceding them;
> and he approached Jesus to kiss Him.

Is it possible that God would have allowed Jesus more time to bring more "sheep" into the fold if the disciples had not failed? Perhaps. But in any case what he sought to avoid here was his immediate arrest, suffering and death.

**We can reject the idea of this being the cup of God's wrath because Jesus had done nothing to anger God. The cup of redemption can also be dismissed since Jesus would not seek to avoid redemption, assuming he needed it.  The cup that Jesus hoped to avoid drinking from in Luke 22 was the cup of suffering and death.**

Answer (score 0):

The Greek word "cup" ποτήριον is used in two senses:

- literally - **a vessel used for drinking**, Matt 10:42, 23:25, 26:27, Mark 7:4, 8, 9:41, 14:23, Luke 11:49, 22:17, 20, 1 Cor 11:25, 26, etc
- figuratively (in the OT ποτήριον is an expression for destiny in both good and bad senses, for death in general ... [incl] the concept of drinking a cup of suffering), John 18:11, Matt 20:22, 23, 26:39, 42, Mark 10:38, 39, 14:36, Luke 22:42, Rev 14:10, 16:19, 18:6, etc.

That is, "cup" was either used literally as in a normal drinking vessel, or, figuratively/metaphorically of destiny such as future suffering or death.

I see no literary/verbal connection between the NT "cup" as listed above and Ex 6 or Isa 53.  [There may be good theological connections but that is not the subject of this site.]  Further, there is no "cup of redemption" in either Ex 6 or Isa 53, nor any other cup there.

Comment: It also gets used to refer to the contents that the cup is holding.  An English example would be, "This cup is wine, but that cup is water".

Answer (score 0):

"The spirit indeed is willing, but the flesh is weak"- [image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/51739)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).